# How to uppercase the first character of each word using a regex in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, regex, ssis

Is it possible to uppercase the first character of each word using regex?

I'm going to be using this in VB.net (SSIS)

Comment: You should either specify a programming language, or ask for a language agnostic answer.

Comment: @Jeremy: I added the VB.NET equivalent to my response

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**EDIT:** VB.NET code added below

```
Dim input As String = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
Dim pattern As String = "\b(\w|['-])+\b"
' With lambda support:
Dim result As String = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, _
    Function (m) m.Value(0).ToString().ToUpper() & m.Value.Substring(1))
```

If you can't use lambdas then use a MatchEvaluator instead:

```
Dim evaluator As MatchEvaluator = AddressOf TitleCase
Dim result As String = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, evaluator)

Public Function TitleCase(ByVal m As Match) As String
    Return m.Value(0).ToString().ToUpper() & m.Value.Substring(1)
End Function
```

It's not really Title case in the sense of the MS Word formatting, but close enough.

---

You didn't specify the language, but in C# you could do this:

```
string input = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
string pattern = @"\b(\w|['-])+\b";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern,
                    m => m.Value[0].ToString().ToUpper() + m.Value.Substring(1));
```

This nicely handles one letter words, as Substring won't throw an error on something such as "A" in the input.

Comment: In which scenarios are lambdas not available in VB.NET and/or C# please?

Comment: @MagnusSmith when using the versions that didn't support them, namely C# 2.0 and VB.NET 8.0 (typically associated with Visual Studio 2005, and .NET 2.0).

Answer (score 29):

Why not just use the inbuilt [TextInfo.ToTitleCase() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx) already in the .NET Framework?

```
string capitalized = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase("this string should be capitalized!");
```

Comment: Didn't know about this.  Could be a great solution for me.  Thanks!

Comment: Just a quick note here. To ensure the first letter of each word is capitalised you first need to convert the original string to lowercase. My original string was all caps and `.ToTitleCase` didn't seem to be having an effect.

Answer (score 7):

```
Dim s As String = "your string"
Dim s2 As String = StrConv(s, VbStrConv.ProperCase
MessageBox.Show(s2)
```

Answer (score 5):

.NET has builtin support for this. See [TextInfo.ToTitleCase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase.aspx) for documentation.

My code contains some extension methods for C#. I assume VB.NET has those too, but I do not know VB.NET well enough to convert them myself.

```
public static class StringExtensions {
    public static string ToTitleCase(this string value) {
        return value.ToTitleCase(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }

    public static string ToTitleCase(this string value, CultureInfo culture) {
        return value.ToTitleCase(culture.TextInfo);
    }

    public static string ToTitleCase(this string value, TextInfo textInfo) {
        return textInfo.ToTitleCase(value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
 s/\b(\w+)\b/ucfirst($1)/ge
```

Comment: Nice and easy -- `s/\b(\w+)/\u$1/g` or `s/\b(\w)/\U\1/g` for short.  Unfortunately, the question now specifies VB.NET, so this Perl answer is no longer relevant...

Answer (score 2):

Not in "pure" regex, but most platform-specific implementations have a way to do it:

For example, in python:

```
import re
re.compile(r'\b\w').sub(lambda x: x.group(0).upper(), 'hello')
```

In this case we pass a callable lambda to the sub() method (rather than a replacement string) that will return the matching string upper cased. Most languages have some equivalent where you pass a callable as the 'replacement'.

In VB.NET you can pass your 'replacement' lambda as `Function (x) x.Value(0).ToString().ToUpper()`

Answer (score 2):

Use `ProperCase` function:

```
Dim Str As String = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
Dim NewStr As String = StrConv(Str, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do that, however this is a pretty common function in most programming languages.  For example, the function is ucwords($word) in PHP.

Comment: I've never used PHP, but don't recall this method in other languages I've used, although I could have just not noticed it.

Answer (score 0):

Do this on key press event of your text box.

```
If e.KeyChar <> ChrW(Keys.Back) Then
            If txtEname.Text = "" Then
                e.KeyChar = UCase(e.KeyChar)
            End If


        End If
```