# VB.NET function for uppercasing the first letter of each word

Tags: vb.net, uppercase

I'm looking for do this in VB.NET,

```
hy how are you
```

to,

```
Hy How Are You
```

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using regular expressions. There are a useful class named Regex that will help you a lot. Please [follow this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668117/regex-how-to-uppercase-the-first-character-of-each-word) for more information.

Comment: `ToTitleCase` makes this easier.

Answer (score 21):

This following will do what you want without using regex (and is more readable than a regex solution):

```
Dim s As String = "some sentence that i want to capitalise"
Debug.WriteLine(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(s))
```

Output:

```
Some Sentence That I Want To Capitalise
```

And you can also do this (from the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` Namespace):

```
Debug.WriteLine(StrConv(s, VbStrConv.ProperCase))
```