# Capitalise each word

Tags: vb.net

I want to capitalise the value of the property. Take a look

```
Public WriteOnly Property setName() As String
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        name = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: u can use the toupper() function , check the documentation here:http://www.dotnetperls.com/toupper-vbnet

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to uppercase the first character of each word using a regex in VB.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668117/how-to-uppercase-the-first-character-of-each-word-using-a-regex-in-vb-net)

Comment: The ToUpper() function capitalises the whole word. I just want the first letters of each word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use StrConv with the ProperCase argument.

```
Public WriteOnly Property setName() As String
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        Name = StrConv(value, VbStrConv.ProperCase)
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: This is already stated in the **duplicate**: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7794618/1842065) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21285029/1842065)