# Can .NET RegEx capitalize letters without .ToUpper()?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, adfs

I am trying to use [ADFS Claims Rule Language](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16161.ad-fs-2-0-using-regex-in-the-claims-rule-language.aspx) for a simple task: capitalize some text. The language *does not* have common string manipulation methods like `.ToUpper()`, but it *does* have a [Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) macro using .NET regular expressions.

Sadly, .NET regex does not support [Perl's `\U` operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/replacecase.html) which would do the trick nicely (e.g. `s/[a-z]/\U\1/g`).

Is there any way a plain `Regex.Replace(string, string, string)` command can capitalize letters **without** using `.ToUpper()` and the like?

Comment: As an aside - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh599320.aspx

Comment: @nzpcmad Yup, I think that's what we'll have to end up doing: creating a custom attribute store DLL with the string manipulation functions we need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No**

See [Substitutions in Regular Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0.aspx). Only the following substitution elements are supported: `$number`, `${name}`, `$$`, `$&`, `` $` ``, `$'`, `$+`, `$_`. You can't transform elements, use conditions or anything like this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a simple way to do it in the expression in .NET, but you could use a MatchEvaluator lambda in the call to Regex.Replace() similar to what is described here:

[How to uppercase the first character of each word using a regex in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668117/how-to-uppercase-the-first-character-of-each-word-using-a-regex-in-vb-net)

Comment: From the question: `The language does not have common string manipulation methods like .ToUpper()`. The linked question uses `.ToUpper()`.

Comment: Karl, that's because what I'm saying is the correct answer; you can't do it in the expression itself in .NET. However, you CAN do it in the function call via a match evaluator lambda and, yes, .ToUpper() is involved, but it is at least in a single Regex function call rather than a multi-step process. You can also implement a workaround that does a ToUpper() a different way, but otherwise the OP may be out of luck.

Comment: No the correct answer is that it can't be done using regex within his constraints. If he can write his own string manipulation for `.ToUpper()` then he probably wouldn't need regex at all.

Comment: I already said I didn't think it was possible within the expression in .Net. I offered a possible alternative out of courtesy, just in case. Whether or not it's supported by the API he's using, I don't know, but it's an avenue to investigate in hopes that he's not completely out of options.

Answer (score -1):

As Colin said, the MatchEvaluator is your best bet. You can do something like this to capitalise the first letter of a statement:

```
var s = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace
        ("capitalise the first letter of this sentence.", "(.*)", 
        delegate(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m) {
                        return (m.Value.Length > 0 ? m.Value.Substring
        (0, 1).ToUpper() : "") + (m.Value.Length > 1 ? m.Value
        .Substring(1, m.Value.Length-1) : "");
                    });
```

Comment: From the question: `The language does not have common string manipulation methods like .ToUpper()`